# Cosmos SQL API logging to Application Insights from a Console Application?

Tags: console-application, azure-cosmosdb, azure-application-insights, .net-framework-version

I'm doing some testing & prototyping with Cosmos DB (SQL API) from a .NET Framework Console Application and I would like to see the Cosmos DB calls appear in Application Insights.
I've set my instrumentation key in Main(), however I don't see any telemetry output by Cosmos.

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "...";
```

Will this only occur in a Web App project?
Is there any way I can configure Cosmos to send telemetry in a console application?

EDIT:
I'm using a C# .NET Framework Console Application template in Visual Studio 2017. I've added the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights NuGet package v2.4.0.
If I set the InstrumentationKey as above, I do get output from the TelemetryClient() objects I create and use, but I don't have any dependency telemetry from the Cosmos DB Library I use. (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB, v 1.19.0).

Thanks

-John

Comment: Can you clarify which App Insights package version are you using and what type of console application (.NET or .NET Core) are you creating?

Comment: Added more info to the post. Thanks Matias.